# I cannot see my grid view when running the website

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my asp.net website project, I need to use a grid view that fetches data from my access database. I though I knew how to do that. But apparently something is missing. I configured the AccessDataSource to my table in the database, and did a grid view to show the contents of this table. but still when I run the website I can't get the grid to show. What could be wrong with my code?

and another question. when I do make it run, I need to get the value of a cell in that grid when I click it. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing you need to check is weather your database table have data or not. if the records fetched from the access database is null then you will not see any gridview as there will be no records. second thing is check the datasource once again if and check the access query to see what result it is providing.

Comment: Thanks moiz it's working now.. i don't know what the problem was. I just started over and it works. can you please tell me how to get the value of a cell by clicking on it ? i need to get it and send it to another form

Comment: why you want to click on cell ? i would suggest you to put one button in the gridview and then on click on gridview you can fetch the value you want and send where ever u want

Answer (score 0):

Press F11 to debug through the code. Maybe you not even calling the function which does datagrid databinding.